# Add variable into (specify text field) on the previous page

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html

I have been looking for a way to add the information (string) from a variable in the previous page.

As far as I know this should be possible using javascript somehow.

**New one** couldn't get the old one to work properly..

```
<script type="text/javascript">
function newPopup(url) {
    popupWindow = window.open(
        url,'popUpWindow','height=510,width=350,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<a href="JavaScript:newPopup('(url)');">Armory Avatar</a>
```

I have that piece of code that opens the link into a new popup window(which remembers the url of the previous page). 
In this window people can insert some information about there WoW character and the realm this character is on. After they do this and hit submit the site displays the url for the avatar retrieved from the blizzard armory.

http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/(imagepath)

Code for the popup page: **Updated this current code (7-4-2012)**

```
   <?php
if (!isset($_POST['submit'])) { 
?>
<!-- The fill in form -->
<html>
<head>
<title>Armory Avatar</title>
</head>
<body>
<form method="post" action="<?php echo $PHP_SELF;?>">
Character Name:<input type="text" size="12" maxlength="50" name="cname"><br />
Realm Name:
<select name="rname">
<optgroup label="English Realms">
<option value="aerie-peak">Aerie-Peak</option>
<option value="agamaggan">Agamaggan</option>
<option value="aggramar">Aggramar</option>
etc etc etc.
</optgroup>
</select><br />
<input type="submit" value="submit" name="submit">
</form>
<?php
} else {  //If form is submitted execute this

    $charname = $_POST["cname"]; //input character name
    $realmname = $_POST["rname"]; //input realm name

    $charurl = urlencode(utf8_encode($charname)); //prepares character name for url usage
    $realmurl = 'http://eu.battle.net/api/wow/character/'.$realmname.'/';  //combines the basic url link with the realm name
    $toon = $realmurl.$charurl; //adds the charactername behind the realm url
    $data = @file_get_contents($toon); //retrieves the data from the armory api
        if ($data) {
            // if armory data is found execute this 

            $obj = json_decode($data); //converts the data from json to be used in the php code ?>
            <img src='http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/<?php echo $obj->thumbnail; ?>'> </img><br /> <?php //Is url link to image 
            $armoryname = utf8_decode($obj->name); //makes the name readable again
            echo "Name: " . $armoryname . "<br />";  //character name
            echo "Level: " . $obj->level . "<br />";  //character level
            echo "Achievement Points : " . $obj->achievementPoints . "<br />"; //Achievement Points
            if ( $obj->gender == 1 ){  //Deteremines the gender of the character
                echo "Gender : Female <br />" ;  //displays gender as female
            }else{
                echo "Gender : Male <br />" ; //dispalays gender as male
            } 
            $image = "http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/".$obj->thumbnail;
            ?>
            Image: <a href='http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/<?php echo $obj->thumbnail; ?>'> http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/<?php echo $obj->thumbnail; ?></a><br /> 


            <!--Button submit code-->

            <script type="text/javascript">
            $('button.cancel_link').click(function() {

            // Change the value of the input with an ID of 'avatarurl'
            // with the dynamic value given to you by the external JSON link

            window.opener.getElementById('avatarurl').value = '<?php echo $image; ?>';

            });
            </script>
            <input> <!-- The button here -->



        <?php   



        }
        else { // if armory data is not found execute this  ?>

            error code stuf
        }
}
?>
```

Now i need this line of code:

$image = "http://eu.battle.net/static-render/eu/".$obj->thumbnail;

To be returned when the window is closed or simply by hitting another submit button(prefered to happen on close over button). And when either of those happen it needs to insert this into this string:

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="avatarurl" size="25" maxlength="100" value="{$avatarurl}" /></td>
```

The texbox called avatarurl.

Hopefully any of you know how to modify or create a javascript that does this for you. Since my php is already severely limited and my javascript knowledge is next to none.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to modify the way you're closing your pop-up window. Try something like this:

```
// When a BUTTON with the class name 'cancel_link'
// is clicked, it activates the following

$('button.cancel_link').click(function() {

   // Change the value of the input with an ID of 'avatarurl'
   // with the dynamic value given to you by the external JSON link

   window.opener.getElementById('avatarurl').value = '<?php echo $image; ?>';

});
```

You need to make sure your closing link has `cancel_link` as its class name, and that your input element in your parent document has an id of `avatarurl`.

Comment: You are talking about a link with class name 'cancel_link' i think you meant a button with that class name or? The second question: The value returned is only the last part of the URL wouldnt it be easier to return $image ? since then i have the complete URL immediately.

Comment: The only question i have now is: ID of 'avatarurl' what ID do you exactly mean with this since i cant find any ID number.

Comment: Also changed the PopUp link code if this would cause any issues please say (since the old one didnt function).

Comment: And another silly question maybe but if i could get it to work could i also change window.open to window.close? since after getting this link putting it into the required textfield the window can be closed.

Comment: Any element (like 'avatarurl') can have what's called an ID. This is something you make up and assign it. For example: `<input type="text" id="someID">`. You don't 'find' something's ID, you _assign_ it yourself. And no, you can't. For one, it's not `window.open` it's `window.opener` - which tells the JavaScript to handle the parent window which OPENED the pop-up box you're on now. If you don't use this, JavaScript won't know what you're asking it.

Comment: I think im still not getting it (i updated the code with how it looks now) but the question that keeps bothering me how do i call this function? Wouldnt it be easier to simply have something like `code <script type="text/javascript">function submitAvatar() {
window.opener.getElementById('avatarurl').value = '<?php echo $image; ?>';}); </script><a href="JavaScript:submitAvatar();">link</a></td>` The other question is how do i add the button below the current code so it calls that java code(Where currently it says <input> <!--button here-->. Sorry for asking so many question.

Answer (score 0):

So after searching trying and thanks to @Jamie i knew where to look.

I found http://www.codingforums.com/showthread.php?t=213298
And this was finally the thing that worked.

On the php page to open it i added:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

function open_pop(){
window.open('armory.php','AvatarArmory','height=510,width=350,left=10,top=10,resizable=yes,scrollbars=yes,toolbar=yes,menubar=no,location=no,directories=no,status=yes')
}
</script>
<html>
.....
<input type="button" value = "OpenArmory" onClick="open_pop()" />
```

And added `id="blogbox"` to the input for the textbox.

```
<input type="text" class="textbox" name="avatarurl" size="45" value="{$avatarurl}" id="blogbox"/>
```

On the armory.php page i added this button with the javascrip function:

```
<script type="text/javascript">

            function pops(avatar){
            textcontent=opener.document.getElementById("blogbox").value;
            opener.document.getElementById("blogbox").value = textcontent + " " + avatar;
            }
            </script>
            <input type="button" value = "Insert Avatar.." onClick="pops('<?php echo $image; ?>');window.close()" />
```

And that worked perfectly.

Thank you jamie for the help.